# Call to undefined function pspell_new() windows

Tags: php

I trying to using pspell on windows. I have followed this link http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/enabling-pspell-in-xampp-on-windows/ to add the extension on php windows.

When I add

```
<?php phpinfo (); ?>
```

in my code I get this

> pspell    Vlad Krupin

under

> Module Authors

But then again I get this error

> Call to undefined function pspell_new()

The apache server logs gives me this warning

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pspell.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

My extension directory in php.ini is

> extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: The module certainly should get listed with a separate section titled `pspell`, not only as authored below. Looks like it does _not_ get loaded in your case.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: I suggest that 1. you monitor your http servers error log file when you restart the apache http server, you will probably find some mentioning _why_ that module fails to load. And 2. you should add the relevant sections of your configuration to the question above, so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Can you please check now.

Comment: Well, that message speaks for itself, doesn't it? The file does not exist where it is expected, thus it cannot be loaded. So what is your question now? _We_ cannot tell you where you placed that file. Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder...

Comment: yeah but I have `aspell-15.dll` and `pspell-15`, should I just rename them like it wants?

Comment: pspell-15 or aspell-15 are not php libraries so it will throw that error then.

Comment: You tell it in the configuration what file to load. That certainly has to match. And indeed that should be a dynamic library, a php extension that can be loaded.

Comment: A side note: I wish MS-Windows would _finally_ get a software management like it is common on other operating systems. Usually such installation is a single click in the software management system which takes care of inter package dependencies, correct location and permission of files on the local system. No searching through the internet on unsafe pages, no downloading of unknown zip files, no manual "installation". Instead MS-Windows users _still_ have to install stuff wild like in medieval times. No wonder so much problems arise...